# multiple digraphs in vim

Tags: vim, hotkeys, digraphs

As you probably know, there is ability to enter some specific characters in vim using digraphs (In input mode Ctrl+K Rg produces ® for example).

Is there a way, to define hotkey, to enter the mode which allows me to input multiple digraphs? For example, to write "sayonara" instead of "Ctrl+K sa Ctrl+K yo Ctrl+K na Ctrl+K ra" to get "さよなら".

Comment: Not much of an answer, but you could `:set digraph` and then type `s <Backspace> a y <Backspace> o` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know. However you can imagine this:

```
exec 'normal! i' . substitute('sayonara', '\(..\)', nr2char(11) . '\1', 'g')
```

nr2char(11) is a CTRL-K character.

If you want a mapping for that (for example in visual mode hit F1 over the selection to transform it; use this on one-line characterwise selection only):

```
xnoremap <f1> d:exec 'normal! a' . substitute(@", '\(..\)', nr2char(11) . '\1', 'g')<ENTER>
```

There might be more proper ways to do that (without erasing the contents of the default register) but I will be too lazy for today. I suspect some Stackers might want to post another answer with cleaner code, they'll get my upvote.

Comment: It is possible to use self-documentary `"\<c-k>"` instead of `nr2char(11)`, if I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but the given answer seems unnecessarily complex.

`iab sayonara さよなら`

In your `.vimrc` will mean that every time you type `sayonara` you'll get `さよなら`

See `:help abbreviations` - `iab` is 'insert abbreviation' which I use extensively for bad spellings, digraph substitution etc.