# How to enter digraph mode permanently in vim/neovim

Tags: vim, unicode, neovim, digraphs

I want to enter digraph mode `Ctrl+k` permanently, so that i can type multiple digraphs at once, forexample typing a sentence in greek letters. or typing multiple languages, like japanese, chinese, greek, etc. without changing input language.

How can I do that?

#### Related

The only related answer on stackoverflow is this:
[multiple digraphs in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907551/multiple-digraphs-in-vim)
which doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this plugin, though I haven't used it myself: https://github.com/potamides/painless-digraph

What I have in my config for Japanese in particular is this "keymap" file: [~/.vim/keymap/kana.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/Vimfiles/blob/d78d70c6b071a9bed93a8df9e211017679288240/keymap/kana.vim). With this in my config, invoking `:set keymap=kana` will activate this mode and let me write ひらがな and かたかな with their digraphs. I don't know where you could find other language-specific ones, but you could google for "vim keymap" and/or learn more from [`:help mbyte-keymap`](https://vimhelp.org/mbyte.txt.html#mbyte-keymap)

Comment: PainlessDigraph is exactly the plugin i was looking for. Thanks a ton! I tried it, works flawlessly.